# Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner doing the JS codecademy course. Super basic I know. It keeps telling me unexpected token if and I've been trying to debug this for hours. Help please? Thanks in advance!

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours)
if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
}
else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
```

Comment: you are missing the `{}` for the function body

Answer (score 5):

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
    if (numHours >= 8) {
       return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}
```

You're missing the `{}`'s

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't seem to be wrapped in curly braces.

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours){
if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
}
else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
}
```

Should work.
Welcome!